# Automatically appearing completion menu on type

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

If I'm typing command in the shell it's required to press `[tab]` to call completion menu. Is it possible to configure zsh to call this menu on each typed symbol but without any modification of my already typed input?

If it is possible only with plugins, I don't mind.